# Search Facets - Entity Type

Tags: search

I want to create a facet to filter search results by entity type (node and product in this case). I have the entity_type field added to my index ...

[image]

And I have a facet set up that seems like it should work ...

[image]

The content_type facet works and is set up essentially the same way.

Any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Not possible to say. One reason a facet won't show is if it has no results, are you 100% positive there are stored results for that field?

Comment: I changed the "Empty facet behavior" to show some text and still nothing. The search results include both types. Does that mean there are "stored results for that field"?

Comment: I can display the entity type in my search results view and also sort by it. However, I cannot expose a filter for it.

Comment: Found it ... I had changed and added and removed the facet so many times trying to make it work I forgot to add the block back in place. It's been a long week.

Comment: Oh, but also if you select "List item label" under the Facet Settings, it doesn't show and throws an error... I suppose because entities don't necessarily have human-readable names?